# Canvas use a letter instead of a shape?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have written up an example, being new to canvas I need help transforming a basic circle into a letter.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3KK3/3/)

Here is the code you will see in the fiddle. Note the circle drawing is what is in the center of the canvas, I am trying to use a letter like B with a cool font in place of the circle, I am just not sure how to implement this.

So just imagine where the circle is a letter being in that spot, still transparent with a rectangle overlaying the image with the color `rgba(255,255,255,0.7)`.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');

// resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    /**
     * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
     * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
     */
    drawStuff();
}
resizeCanvas();

function drawStuff() {

    if (canvas.getContext) {

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 70;

        // Full rectangle
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        // Inner circle
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

        // Add a letter instead of a circle?

        // Hmm
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        context.fill();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
context.strokeStyle = "#F00";
context.font = "bold 60pt Arial";
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.fillText("B", 20, 50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pqD87/

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';` is what was making the circle transparent, cool. But I did use `fillText` and got the same result the text over in the upper left corner, is there a way to center it like a circle. I am sure I can google that, but definitely giving you credit if you can help me figure that out.

Comment: Oh `context.fillText("B", centerX, centerY);` I didnt know those arguments were position, now I do!

Comment: well, it is here for example http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-text-align/

Comment: Canvas documentation is actually pretty good, but when I was going through all the docs there was just so many different tuts plus reading, so I wanted a specific answer, Ill be going through the docs now that I am getting the hang of things, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here again with centering

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.textAlign = 'center';
context.font="150px Times";
context.fillText("A",centerX,centerY+40);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4BuF/1/

Comment: Yeah I agree, `context.fillText("B", centerX, centerY);` does not center it perfectly. I will have to think of something. Does the letter seem a little jagged to you?

Comment: I am getting inspiration from this site http://www.jcsuzanne.com/#/project/thomas-ciszewski-photography/ and the letter is crisp!

Comment: The letter is pretty smooth in firefox. In Chrome it isn't but the font rendering of Chrome under Windows is awful anyway :p

Comment: Awesome I would give you another +1 for that edit nice, times is ugly though imo lol http://jsfiddle.net/x4BuF/2/ updated with arial bold haha. Thanks!

Comment: Why the +40 though any reason you got that number? It obviously centers it better, was it a guess or a reason?

Comment: nah I just fiddled with it until it was centered inside the circle before removing it